# Do boolean logical operators (|| and &&) cause branching?

Tags: c#

With boolean operators, the right-hand operand is executed conditionally. I.e.

```
var a = b || DoStuff();
```

DoStuff() is only executed if b evaluates to false. Which I suppose is at least logically equivalent to

```
var a = b;
if(!a)
  a = DoStuff();
```

Now I'm curious, do these logical operators actually result in a branching instruction for the CPU?

If so, could it actually be preferable from a performance point of view to use logical operators (| and &) in case all operands are very cheap to evaluate, in order to avoid branch mispredictions?

Comment: `could it actually be preferable from a performance point of view to use logical operators (| and &)` - those are bitwise, not logical, and they will ensure that `DoStuff()` will be called regardless of `b`, which is likely to be way more expensive on average. And it [keeps people out of their Chromebooks](https://www.theverge.com/2021/7/23/22590425/chrome-os-release-bricked-ampersand-typo-reddit-update).

Comment: When using IF : yes (use for example [ILSpy](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/api/system.reflection.emit.opcodes)). In target machine code they are replaced by [flow control mnemonics](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/X86_Assembly/Control_Flow)) : CMP (can be ommited in special cases) and next JE, JNE, JZ, JNZ... (the IF part) branching. Here there is branching even with the first line because of calling a method. Sometimes branching can be avoid in certain cases.